# can somebody explain what this function does?

Tags: python

I am doing online coding questions, and this is the recommended format to take inputs from the website:

```
numStudents = map(int, input().split())
```

I'm also wondering how I'm meant to know what type of output the website is giving if they're not directly telling me.

Comment: You should try to solve this for yourself. Hint: run that line of code, then type: `1 2 3` and see what it does. `print(numStudents)` is helpful.

Comment: Do you know what `input()` does, what `str.split()` does, what `int()` does and finally what `map()` does? If the answer is No to any of these, did you do basic reserach, like check the docs?

Comment: @smci It'll return the map object.

Comment: Instead try `print(list(numStudents))`

Comment: Please see why ["what does this code do ?" questions type are off topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79133/are-what-does-this-code-do-questions-on-topic-at-stackoverflow)

Comment: @karel, in addition to link posted above, this question show no research effort whatsoever, so it's worth a downvote.

Comment: @buran Thanks for enlightening me because after reading two contrasting opinions I got confused and didn't know who to ask  for clarification.

Comment: @karel, the very good answer in the link you pasted has a section "you need to do the following:". I suggest you review the list then come back to the above question and see how many ticks you can put in front of each suggested item (hint: none). Moreover, the answer is given in a very specific case: "someone gave me a code only answer and I don't know how to ask for clarification". We are lightyears away from this here.

Comment: I apologize sincerely for posting this question... I'm still new to programming and I didn't know where else to look or ask..

Answer (score 0):

**map()** function takes 2 arguments: First a function and then an iterable. It applies the function to each element in the iterable and returns a new iterable.
**split()** function takes a single parameter: Which character/string to split the string with. If none is specified then it defaults to whitespace(' ').
**input()** just asks the user to enter a line. It interprets everything as a singular string.

```
numStudents = map(int, input().split())
```

So this code asks the user to enter a line, splits this string based on whitespace and then converts each of those splitted strings to int and returns it as a new map object. It is usually followed by **list()** function like this to convert it into a list:

```
numStudents = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

Comment: _and returns it as a new array_ - `map()` returns `map` object, lazily evaluated.

Comment: Thank you, fixed it hopefully. I always followed it with list() to convert it into a list. Completely forgot that.